# Fastest way of sorting multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[t] => 81881
[b] => 99494
)
[1] => Array
(
)
...
...
)
```

I have a multidimensional array like above.The entries in this array would be ranging upto 20k. I want to sort this array acc. to "t" index without calling any external function. Any suggestions for improving the efficiency.

Comment: Define: "without calling any external function"

Comment: have you looked at [array_multisort](http://us2.php.net/array_multisort)?

Comment: m.d. for multidimensional and acc. for according are not standard shortcuts as far as I know

Comment: Improving the efficiency of what? I can't see any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is something faster than `array_multisort()` https://www.php.net/array_multisort

UPDATE:

Finding out now, that data is not really multidimensional (it's just a key that's hidden as a val of item in array). It would be probably easier to use something like:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $a['t']<=>$b['t'];
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Please give an example how to use `array_multisort` in this case.