# Array sorting faster than array_multisort?

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort a large array based on a column of orders. The way the array is built doesn't allow me to do much in the query to sort, but I would like to know if there is a way that's faster than [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array-multisort) in PHP?

My code is:

```
foreach ($returnArr as $key => $row) {
    $tmp[$key] = $row['orders'];
}

array_multisort($tmp, SORT_DESC, $returnArr);
```

I'm also up for suggestions on how I can build a single query and have some of my where conditions only apply to a single column. If this is possible, then I would just be able to do it with MySQL rather than PHP.

Comment: **See the following question:**<br />
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710457/fastest-way-of-sorting-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without your query, but I doubt if multisort is what you want. It essentially sorts your column names as well, which you could easily do in the query itself. You can also let the database sort the values for you, so your query would look something like:

```
select
  Col_AAA, Col_BBB, Col_HHH, Col_ZZZ
from
  YourTable
order by
  Col_AAA, Col_BBB, Col_HHH, Col_ZZZ
```

This will return the values sorted, and the column in the order in which you specify them.

Answer (score 0):

If `array_multisort()` is the answer, then the question is wrong. I have yet to see a case where array_multisort was necessary, PHP arrays are such a strong data structure that multisorting is not really necessary.

Why do you fetch all the orders from `$returnArr` and then sort this array together with $tmp? You should simply sort $tmp in a way that keeps it's array keys as well, and if you want to iterate this $tmp array, the key inside the foreach is the same that also points to $returnArr - you have access to the matching data set in $returnArr without having to sort it. Same keys in $tmp and $returnArr will always belong to the same dataset.

On the other hand, you did not state anything about what you want to do.